# Animate half covered image with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery that hides half a div that contains an image and after 3 seconds displays the full size of the image. It works great in FireFox and IE but not Chrome. Any ideas why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var status = "closed";
        var banner = jQuery.noConflict();
        banner(document).ready(function () {
            var sliderHalfHeight = "46px";
            var sliderFullHeight = "86px";

            // set at half height
            banner('#banner').css('height', sliderHalfHeight);  

            var autoTimer = null;

            autoTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                banner("#banner").animate({ height: sliderFullHeight }, 'slow');
                autoTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    banner("#banner").animate({ height: sliderHalfHeight });
                }, 5000);
            }, 2000);

            banner("#open").click(function () {
                if (status == "closed") {
                    banner("#banner").animate({ height: sliderFullHeight });
                    if (autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
                    autoTimer = null;
                    status = "open";
                }
                else {
                    banner("#banner").animate({ height: sliderHalfHeight });
                    if (autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
                    autoTimer = null;
                    status = "closed";
                }
            });


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="banner" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <img src="banner.jpg" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div id="open">Open/Close</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your use of the jQuery object as the banner variable makes the code really confusing to read..

Comment: what part of it does not work in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to working just fine in Chrome for me, try this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HNpwB/

Comment: yeah..i cleared the browser cache and its working now for me.